# What is the abbreviation for "accept" or "acceptance?"

Tags: abbreviations

What is the preferred abbreviation for "accept" or "acceptance?"  Is it "acc," "acpt" or some other abbreviation?

Comment: What if there is no generally accepted abbreviation?  Because I think that is the case...